# How to set 2 different themes for Mobile and Desktop in Magento 2.1.7 without changing the core file

Tags: magento-2.1, user-roles, theme-fallback, mobile-device

I am working on Magento store version 2.1.
I'm required to show a different layout and design on the Mobile device, which is different from my default view. 
For this I added a theme in the root folder of Magento store.
I am trying to add this user string -

```
iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini
```

I also tried this code -

```
iPad|iPhone|Android ((?!(2\.|3\.|4\.0)).)
```

I also added this code in my `index.php` -

```
$mobile_agents = "/(nokia|iphone|android|motorola|^mot\-|softbank|foma|docomo|kddi|up\.browser|up\.link|"  
                 . "htc|dopod|blazer|netfront|helio|hosin|huawei|novarra|CoolPad|webos|techfaith|palmsource|"  
                 . "blackberry|blackberry10|bb10|playbook|alcatel|amoi|ktouch|nexian|samsung|^sam\-|s[cg]h|^lge|ericsson|philips|sagem|wellcom|bunjalloo|maui|"  
                 . "symbian|smartphone|mmp|midp|wap|phone|windows ce|iemobile|^spice|^bird|^zte\-|longcos|pantech|gionee|^sie\-|portalmmm|"  
                 . "jig\s browser|hiptop|^ucweb|^benq|haier|^lct|opera\s*mobi|opera\*mini|320x320|240x320|176x220"  
                 . ")/i";  
if (preg_match($mobile_agents, strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
     $mageRunCode = 'mobile';  // your store view code
}
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

But nothing is helpful for me.

If anyone knows how to achieve this please write here.

My web URL is - https://www.anytimehydration.com

Comment: Check out the Design Configuration section of the dev docs step #4. http://docs.magento.com/m2/2.1/ce/user_guide/design/configuration.html. I've yet to try this feature before but it appears to me that is along the lines of what you're asking for.

Comment: Hello Mat thank you for your revert. Stil I am unable to find the actual string what will be placed if I am using theme for android and iphone. Can you help in this please.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need a second theme for mobile? do you want to have different templates?
Magento 2 is mobile first, you should learn how to theme in magento 2.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd_css.html

Comment: Yesh i am very sure about that I need a different theme for mobile. Because I want to display different slider images and different block  in mobile. Only footer will be same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by defining user agent rules under Design Configuration.

**Content -> Design -> Configuration**

Click on edit button of respective website theme setting and add new user agent rule.

**Design Rule -> User Agent Rules -> Add New User Agent Rule**

Refer to [this](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/design/configuration.html) for more information and [this](https://docs.magento.com/m2/pdf/ce/Magento-Community-Edition-2.1-User-Guide.pdf) for M2.1